# how to connect a programmed raspberry pi to a Kaa platform?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sandbox, iot, kaa

I have some sensor nodes. they are connected to a Raspberry Pi 2 and send data on it. the data on Raspberry Pi is sending the data to Thingspeak.com and it shows the data from sensor nodes. 
now I am developing a Kaa server and wanna see my data (from Raspberry Pi) on Kaa. is there any chance to connect the current programmed Raspberry Pi(in Python) to Kaa? 
Many thanks, 
Shid

Comment: *typo: the data on Raspberry Pi is sent to Thingspeak.com

Answer (score 0):

Mashid. From what I know, to use a KAA server, you should utilize the SDK obtained when you create a new application on the KAA server. This SDK also functions as an API key that will connect the device with a KAA server (on a KAA server named with Application Token). The platforms provided for using this SDK are C, C ++, Java, Android, and Objective C. There is currently no SDK for the Python platform.

Comment: yea now I understand. I already have the Java SDK (forgetting about Python!). But now how can I change the code through this SDK? And how can I use this SDK?